# I'm trying to make a simple hangman game, but I run into this error: String index out of range: 0 at line 19

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
 public class Hangman2
 { 


 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 

     final int LETTERCOUNT = 6; 
     char [] letters = { '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'}; 
     String input = "";
     int noOfGuesses = 0, count; 
     char guesses = input.charAt(0);
     Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in); 

     System.out.println ("The word has " + LETTERCOUNT + "letters"); 

     do{
         noOfGuesses = noOfGuesses+1; 
     }while (noOfGuesses > 0);

     System.out.println ("Please enter your guess"); 
     char guess = input.charAt (0); 

     for (count = 0; count <6; count ++) { 
         char letter[]={'_','_','_','_',' ','_'}; 
     }

     for(int i=0; i<letter.length;i++){ 
         if(letter[i]==' '){ // Note use ' '(' + Blank Space + ') instead of '' 
         System.out.print("Blank Space"); 
         letter[i]='M'; 
     } 

     System.out.println("(" + i + ")" + letter[i]); 

     } 
 }
```

I'm not sure what to try. Any pointers would be nice.

Comment: You've just blown my mind with that `do-while` loop.

Comment: This seems to be a problem: `input.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 2):

If we have a little look at this...

```
String input = "";
int noOfGuesses = 0, count;
char guesses = input.charAt(0);
```

You create an empty `String`, then try and get the `char` at position `0`...when nothing exists ...

I'm "guessing" that `input` was suppose to take input from the user in some way, but given the fact that you initialise the `Scanner` after this, I'm just not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

```
char guesses = input.charAt(0);
```

the variable input is empty. But you are trying to get the 0th index value.